# How to aggregate from a snowflake pivot where keys have distinct value for each row?

Tags: sql

Using snowflake is it possible to pivot table as follows?

I.e. given table A:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| id | key | value |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 | k1  |    11 |
|  1 | k2  |    12 |
|  2 | k1  |    21 |
|  2 | k2  |    22 |
|  3 | k2  |     3 |
+----+-----+-------+
```

returns:

```
+----+------+----+
| id |  k1  | k2 |
+----+------+----+
|  1 | 11   | 12 |
|  2 | 21   | 22 |
|  3 | null |  3 |
+----+------+----+
```

I suspect the query looks like the following but I am not sure how to aggregate:

```
select id, distinct(key)
  from table_a
    pivot table_a on value for value in distinct(key) 
      as p
  order by id;
```

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` and it's invalid "in between columns"

Comment: Thank you, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  It is more flexible and lacks ideosynchracies:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = 'k1' then value end) as k1,
       max(case when key = 'k2' then value end) as k2
from t
group by id;
```